# Which topology should I use for energy harvesting

Tags: boost, electromagnetic, energy, buck-boost, energy-harvesting

I am making a energy harvester design but am confused which of the following circuit should I use to amplify and filter my harvested voltage. The first topology is the synchronous switch harvesting on inductor (SSHI) and the second one is boost converter with feedforward and feedback control. Can someone please point out which one is better and why ?

[image: SSHI]

[image: Boost converter]

Here is the link to the paper

https://www.mdpi.com/2079-9292/10/9/1108

Comment: Before we do your homework for you, you should probably at least give a stab at an analysis. Otherwise, what will you learn? What's your gut reaction? And why? Finally, is the source piezo, or wind power, or solar, or what? Give us more detail.

Answer (score 3):

Since  the [Maximum Power Transfer](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem) (MPT) theorem is based on matched conjugate impedances and neither block diagram shows any means of tracking this by measuring current, I'd say that neither solution is optimal for dynamic sources where source impedance changes with energy available.

Simply put when source/load resistance ratio = 1, you can transfer the maximum theoretical power. However there may be thermal issues.
[image]

IMHO, the presentation reads like it was cut and pasted from many textbooks without real data.

Comment: "it was cut and pasted from many textbooks without real data." It's a review article so, yeah. (Well, academic papers rather than textbooks.)

Comment: most student papers aren't worth much according to my son-in-law EE Prof at U of T. I agree.    and this was one of them.  There are rare exceptions. It takes decades of commercial experience to cover all the importance aspects with specs, tolerances and results

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please point out which one is better

I have no idea myself.

Your link is to a review paper. It's purpose is to briefly review a wide range of source material in a given topic. If parts of that paper are of interest, such as the circuits you show, you should be able to go back to the original papers cited in the review article and get more information.

A quick look suggests the references may be available on Google Scholar. Otherwise a university or business library should be able to obtain them.